# CSRF protection - what happens if an attacker performs a GET request before the POST?

Tags: csrf

I'm implementing a per-page CSRF token in a web app. However, I had a thought. What happens if, before an attacker submits a malicious POST request, they submit a GET request on the page and capture the CSRF token? Is there anything in place that I can protect against an external site requesting data from my web app?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I figured out my own question. If you store the CSRF token in a client cookie then the cross-origin policy prevents it being read.

Comment: I read some articles and posts about CSRF token, and in my understanding all of them suggest to place the CSRF token in a hidden field of the form. If anyone passing by can add a complement about why a hidden field would do, or why my understanding is wrong, would be much appreciated. Thanks !